# What search tree should I use when I know all the probabilities of accessing each element

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

In case if I don't know the probabilities of accessing each element, but I'm sure that some elements will be accessed far more often then the others, I will use [Splay tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). What should I use if I already know all the probabilities? I assume that there should be some data structure that is better than splay trees for this case.

I'm trying to imagine all the cases where and when should I use every type of the search trees. Maybe someone can post some links to articles about comparison of all the search trees, and similar structures?

**EDIT** I'd like to still have `O(log n)` as the worst case, but in avarage it should be faster.  Splay trees are good example, but I'd like to predefine the configuration of this tree.

For example, I have an array of elements to store `[a1, a2, .. an]`, and the probabilities for each element `[p1, p2, .. pn]`, which define how often I will access each element. I can create splay tree, add each element to the splay tree (`O(n log n)`), and then access them with given probabilities to make the desired tree. So if I have probabilities `[1/2, 1/4, 1/4]`, I need to splay the first element, to make it be among the first. So, I need to order elements by probabilities, and splay them in the order from the lowest to the highest access probability. That takes `O(n log n)` also. So, overall time of building such tree is `O(n log n)` with a big constant.  My goal is to lower this number.

I do not mind using something else, but not search tree, but I'd like for the time to be lower then in case of Splay tree. And I want search, insert and delete be in the range of `O(log n)` amortized.

Comment: yes you may use splay tree if just caching exceeds O( log(n) )

Comment: Run your data through the splay tree once, and store its configuration after running the data through it.

Comment: I cannot prove that, but it doesn't sound optimal. It would be great to be able to build this configuration from start, overall amortized time will increase greatly.

Comment: Is there a reason you are considering only trees?  Perhaps you know you need an ordered container, for example.

Comment: Going on a tangent here, but if you know all elements in the tree in advance you could perhaps use a perfect hash function? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: @MartinLiversage Nice catch! But it solves a little more narrow problem - I still would like to be able to add new elements and delete them after building desired structure.

Comment: I don't quite see how you can add and delete elements if you know the probabilities... maybe they aren't probabilities but weights for probabilities (sum != 1)?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I didn't see that you wanted to update the tree dynamically - the below algorithm requires all elements and probabilities to be known in advance. I'll leave the post up in case someone in such a situation comes along.

If you happen to be in possession of the third edition of *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen et al., it describes a dynamic programming algorithm for creating optimal binary search trees when you know all of the probabilities.

Here is a rough outline of the algorithm: First, sort the elements (on element value, not probability). We don't yet know which element should be the root of the tree, but we know that all elements that will be to the left of the root in the tree will be to the left of that element in the list, and vice versa for the elements to the right of the root. If we choose the element at index *k* to be the root, we get two subproblems: how to construct an optimal tree for the elements 0 through *k-1*, and for the elements *k+1* through *n-1*. Solve these problems recursively, so that you know the expected cost for a search in a tree where the root is element *k*. Do this for all possible choices of *k*, and you will find which tree is the best one. Use dynamic programming or memoization in order to save computation time.

Comment: +1 yes this is a nice problem. It resembles with the Matrix multiplication problem around partitioning of array.

Comment: @Ankush: Yes, it's essentially the same algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

You never mentioned needing ordered iteration, and by sacrificing this you can achieve amortized `O(1)` insert/access complexity, better than `O(log n)`.

Specifically, use a hash table with linked list buckets, and use the [move-to-front optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move-to-front_heuristic).  What this means is each time you search a bucket (linked list) with more than one item, you move the item found to the front of that bucket.  The next time you access this element, it will already be at the front.

If you know the access probabilities, you can further refine the technique.  When inserting a new element into a bucket, don't insert it onto the front, but rather insert such that you maintain most-probable-first order.  Note the move-to-front technique will tend to perform this sort implicitly already, but you can help it bootstrap more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is not going to change once created, you probably should use a hash table or tango tree:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree

Hash tables, when not overloaded, are O(1) lookup, degrading to a O(n) when overloaded.

Tango trees, once constructed, are O(loglogn) lookup. They do not support deletion or insertion.

There's also something known as a "perfect hash" that might be good for your use.